# please help in emergency

Tags: math-mode, fonts, amsmath, math-operators, mathtools

[image]

hi everyone could you help me. how can I write in tex

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What did you try?

Comment: If you did not try anything, maybe https://mathpix.com/ will help you get the code for an image.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, this site is not a coding service to create TeX from images.  If you're having trouble creating a specific output, we're happy to help.  But then our question is what aspect of the image is giving you trouble.  Most (all?) of the output is not too difficult even for a newcomer to TeX.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you do not need to use plain TeX (you have `amsmath` in the tags). If yes, some of the following code should be corrected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepacakage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
=\lim_{A\to\infty} \left[
\frac{e^{-(s-a)x)}}{a-s}
\right]_{0}^{A}
\]

\end{document}
```

However, it would be better to start with at least an elementary manual.